# How to retrieve actual type arguments of Spring Data repositories at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Suppose I have this `Repository`:

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {}
```

and I want to know at runtime that this repository persists `Product`s, not `Account`s or anything else. So far I only came up with this solution:

```java
Class<?> persistedClass = ((ParameterizedType) repository.getClass() // some Spring proxy
    .getInterfaces()[0] // ProductRepository or the like
    .getGenericInterfaces()[0]) // JpaRepository
    .getActualTypeArguments()[0] // the first type argument
```

Let's ignore this clumsiness for a moment (isn't it par for the course with Java Reflection API?). What's worse, I had to remove the `--release` option which makes the solution a bit less portable (it's enabled by default in IntelliJ). There's something that makes `java.base` (it's where `ParameterizedType` is) and `--release` not compatible which prevents compilation (I don't understand it very well)

Is there a better way to retrieve that information at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `AbstractRepositoryMetadata.getMetadata(…)` and call `getDomainType()` etc. on the result.

If you're interested in the reverse lookup, i.e. finding a repository for a domain type, you can create a `Repositories(…)` instance from a `ListableBeanFactory` which would find look up all metadata for repository instances registered in that very `BeanFactory`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide a code snippet for the inverse lookup scenario?

Comment: `Repositories` has that. Check it's type signature. Methods to retrieve a repository instance for a managed domain type, repository metadata for the same etc.